# formatting cell values in datatables

Tags: datatables

Using this as an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/evjhre7n/) how do I control the format of the values in the cells?

for example, how would I format the `Extn.` column to read 5,407 or 54.07?

```
Name    Position    Office  Extn.   Start date  Salary
Airi Satou  Accountant  Tokyo   5407    $2008/11/28 $162,700
```

I have been searching [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/formatNumber) and [here](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Built-in-helpers) but I can't quite work it out. can anyone advise?

I have tried something like this, but am having no success:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ],
      "aoColumnDefs": [ {
                    "aTargets": [ 4 ],
                        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                                //var formmatedvalue=data.replace("TEST")
                            //return formmatedvalue;
                  return '$'+ data;
                            }
            }]
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `columns.render` [option](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers).

Either with the [built-in](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Built-in-helpers) helper, to get a thousand seperator (`5,407`):

```
{
  title: "Extn.",
  render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '')
},
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/fx2wsfh1/1/)

Or do it yourself with a custom function (`54.07`):

```
{
    title: "Extn.", render: function (data, type, row) {
        return data / 100;
    }

},
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jf2jx3mr/1/)